# correct axis range (matlab)

Tags: matlab, axis-labels

how can i solve the problem of these two images automatically (with a code adaptable to different data) **without having to fix the axes range for each plot** (i have millions of these plots)?

problem: axis range **should be smaller**

problem: axis range **should be bigger**

also, i need axis to be **correctly labeled from the first value to last** (see example in comment please)

any help is highly appreciated. thank you so so much.

Comment: example: http://i49.tinypic.com/9pxnk4.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: What do you use to plot these? Depends on how you can automatically set the axes' range. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html ?

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/kXnhD/Untitled2.m      - there it is the code. in the figure1 if you go to x-z view you see the  axis range should be bigger and in the 2nd smaller. **in short, i want the plot not  to be completely tighted in the window.** am i explaning myself? thank you very much. any help you can give me is very good to me. thank you.

Comment: also, as i said i need axis to be correctly labeled from the first value to last (as the example in the first comment) and limited by a complete rectangle (limiting the plot). thank you very much.

Comment: Dan, yes i saw. but as i said i want an automatic code as i have millions of these plots and also in your link i don't find the way of doing what i asked in the previous comment. any ideas? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a complete bounding box use `box on`.

In order to avoid large empty space around a plot (or no space at all) use `xlim` and `ylim`. Try the following:

```
figure
plot(x,y)
box on

x1 = min(x);
x2 = max(x);
dx = x2-x1;
y1 = min(y);
y2 = max(y);
dy = y2-y1;

fc = 10/100  % this is a factor of 10% of empty space around plot


xlim([x1-dx*fc x2+dx*fc])
ylim([y1-dy*fc y2+dy*fc])
```

If you want to have a tick value appear at the start and the end of the axis, you could either force it by `set(gca,'Xtick',[values])`, where values are those ticks you want to show; or by `floor` and `ceil` of the xlim and ylim min and max limits above.

Hope this is what you need

Comment: ohh thank you so much for your help, i was trying this for years. i read everything you told me, thank you. but i remembered a new thing to plot correctly. in short what is missing is this http://i49.tinypic.com/5agsn4.jpg[/IMG]. do you have any ideas of how i could achieve this? thank you so much for all your kindness. this is very important to me:) thankk you

Comment: I don't know if Matlab can do broken axes (--//--) but you can set your lower limits (x1 and y1 in my answer) to 0 both.  But this might make your figure too small on the top left corner.

Comment: and what about obligating matlab automatically to write final x value and final y value in the plots? do you have any idea? thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

To set axis limit and visualize chart better you can use axis command like axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]) where parameters set chart borders. It should help you. More information is here:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/axis.html